# Mysqld service is stopping a few minutes after starting. Lots of inserts needed. How can i fix this?

Tags: php, pdo, memcached, mysql

This is both a programming and a server question, so I figure out I better ask this here instead of serverfault. Sorry for the long post...

I have a website which has a dictionary tool. It runs on Centos 6.5 with php 5.4, mysql 5.5.25 and memcache 2.2.6. The dictionary is the only script that uses the mysql service.

Basically, this is what it does:

1. User searches for a word
2. PHP checks for word in memcache:

   - **Word found?** return word+meanings. **END**.
   - **Not found?** Go to **3**.
3. PHP checks for word in mysql with `SELECT word_item.definition, word_item.extra, word.flg_success FROM word LEFT JOIN word_item ON word.id_word = word_item.id_word WHERE word.lang = :lang AND word.word = :word`

   - **Word found?**

     - If `flg_success = 1`, store the word+meanings in memcache and return word+meanings.
     - If `flg_success = 0`, display error. **END**.
   - **Not found?** Go to **4**.
4. PHP connects to an external API and receives a json with the word meanings.

   - **Word found?** Store the word+meanings in memcache, insert word in the **word** table with `flg_success = 1` and meanings in **item**, and return word+meanings.
   - **Not found?** Insert the word in the **word** table with `flg_success = 0`

As you can see, the process is *theoretically* optimized to use mysql only if the word isn't already in memcache (which uses a 30 days expiration date - that's been successfully checked).

---

### table: word (InnoDB) with 26919 records

[image: parent]

---

### table: item (InnoDB) with 76194 records

[image: children]

---

### mysqld log

So, apparently when too many users are searching for words, something happens with the mysql tables and the **mysqld service** is stopped.

After checking the log,

```
tail -40 /var/lig/mysqld.log
```

this is the result:

```
141220 11:35:21 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
141220 11:35:21 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
141220 11:35:21  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 28512664
141220 10:48:04  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percents: 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
141220 10:48:04  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
141220 10:48:05 InnoDB: 5.5.41 started; log sequence number 28512664
141220 10:48:05 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
141220 10:48:05 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
141220 10:48:05 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
141220 10:48:05 [ERROR] Missing system table mysql.proxies_priv; please run mysql_upgrade to create it
141220 10:48:05 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_current' has the wrong structure
141220 10:48:05 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_history' has the wrong structure
141220 10:48:05 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_history_long' has the wrong structure
141220 10:48:05 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'setup_consumers' has the wrong structure
141220 10:48:05 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'setup_instruments' has the wrong structure
141220 10:48:05 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'setup_timers' has the wrong structure
141220 10:48:05 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'performance_timers' has the wrong structure
141220 10:48:05 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'threads' has the wrong structure
141220 10:48:05 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_summary_by_thread_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
141220 10:48:05 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_summary_by_instance' has the wrong structure
141220 10:48:05 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_summary_global_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
141220 10:48:05 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'file_summary_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
141220 10:48:05 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'file_summary_by_instance' has the wrong structure
141220 10:48:05 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'mutex_instances' has the wrong structure
141220 10:48:05 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'rwlock_instances' has the wrong structure
141220 10:48:05 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'cond_instances' has the wrong structure
141220 10:48:05 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'file_instances' has the wrong structure
141220 10:48:05 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
141220 10:48:05 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.41'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL) by Remi
141220 10:54:18 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table mysql.proc: expected column 'comment' at position 15 to have type text, found type char(64).
```

---

### PHP

This function allows the script to connect to the database. It is only fired when a mysql connection is needed.

```
function cnn() {
    static $pdo;
    if(!isset($pdo)) {
        $conf = [
            PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => 30,
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'
        ];
        try {
            # DB Settings
            $config['db']['host'] = 'localhost';
            $config['db']['name'] = 'my_db';
            $config['db']['user'] = 'root';
            $config['db']['pass'] = 'somepassword';
            $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$config['db']['host'].';dbname='.$config['db']['name'], $config['db']['user'], $config['db']['pass'], $conf);
            return $pdo;
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            http_response_code(503);
            echo $e->getCode().': '.$e->getMessage();
            die();
        }
    } else {
        return $pdo;
    }
}
```

---

### MySQL queries in PHP

**Search** for the word:

```
$sql = 'SELECT word_item.definition, word_item.extra, word.flg_success FROM word LEFT JOIN word_item ON word.id_word = word_item.id_word WHERE word.lang = :lang AND word.word = :word';
$stmt = cnn()->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':lang', $lang, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':word', urldecode($word), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

**Insert** new word and meanings

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO word (lang, word, flg_success) VALUES (:lang, :word, :flg_success)';
$stmt = cnn()->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':lang', $lang, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':word', urldecode($word), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':flg_success', true, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$stmt->execute();
if($last_insert_id = cnn()->lastInsertId()) {
    # db: insert new definitions
    foreach($definitions as $k=>$item) {
        $fields[] = '(:id_word, :definition_'.$k.', :extra_'.$k.')';
    }
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO word_item (id_word, definition, extra) VALUES '.implode($fields, ',');
    $stmt = cnn()->prepare($sql);

    # bind parameters
    foreach($definitions as $k=>$item) {
        $stmt->bindValue(':id_word', $last_insert_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':definition_'.$k, $item['definition'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':extra_'.$k, $item['extra'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

        # fill return value
        $result['data'][] = array('definition'=>$item['definition'], 'extra'=>$item['extra']);
    }
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

---

I don't know what's really causing the mysqld service wreckage. I'll be very grateful to know if you have any ideas on where to look or what to optimize.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide (even) more info ? For example the number of entries that you have in your tables, and the different indexes and keys (including foreign keys) that you have set ?

Comment: Hi! I'm not using foreign keys, only indexes. At the time of writing the post, there were 26919 and 76194 records in the word and item tables accordingly.